# Creating a Processor

Tags: c, cpu, cpu-architecture, processor, microprocessors

It is my last semester but one in university, the sublect is called Architecture and Programming of Microprocessors, the professor wrote this code and i just cannot understand what he is doing. Especially the part with the mask. Here is the code. Can anyone help me to understand it please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>


uint32_t Instruction_Memory[0x2000];
uint32_t PC = 0;

uint32_t Registers[32];

uint32_t Data_Memory[0x3000];

uint32_t get_instruction(uint32_t input){
   uint32_t temp = input/4;
   return Instruction_Memory[temp];
}

void print_registers() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
           printf("x%d: %x \t", i*8+j, Registers[i*8+j]);
       }
       printf("\n");
   };
};

uint32_t get_bits(uint32_t input, int start, int numberOfBits){
   uint32_t t4 = input >> start;
   uint32_t mask = (1 << numberOfBits) - 1;

   t4 = mask & t4;
//    printf("input : %x, start : %d, nob : %d, mask : %x\n", input, start, numberOfBits, mask);
   return t4;
}

int main(){


   PC = 0x1000;

//    x5
   Registers[5] = 6;
//    x9
   Registers[9] = 0x2004;

   Data_Memory[0x2000] = 10;

   Instruction_Memory[0x1000 / 4] = 0xFFC4A303;
   Instruction_Memory[0x1004 / 4] = 0x0064A423;
   Instruction_Memory[0x1008 / 4] = 0x0062E233;


   uint32_t instruction = get_instruction(0x1000);

   printf("Instruction = 0x%x\n\r", instruction);

   print_registers();
   uint32_t A1 = get_bits(instruction, 15, 5);
   printf("A1 = %x\n\r", A1);

   return 0;
}
```

I understood that he printed out the registers and also provided an instruction to the system.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And please [edit] your question to be more specific. What "part with the mask"?

Comment: This code doesn't actually do any simulating of a CPU, it just plays around with the arrays that it would use to hold the state of a Harvard machine (separate code vs. data address spaces).  It assigns some values to some register and memory storage spaces, then reads it back and uses the helper functions it's defined.  Address/4 is normal if it's working purely with words, but using byte addresses.

Answer (score 5):

The function `get_bits` (aka "the part with the mask") takes a 32bit integer and two counts. The first count is how many low bits are to be ignored, the second how many are to be returned. (As @PeterCordes pointed out in a comment, the function as-is is not fit for *general* use due to some limitations, but I guess this code is a one-shot to illustrate certain points.)

`get_bits` is called with the values 15 and 5, respectively. This means ignore 15, return 5.

```
Mbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbL
             rrrr riiiiiii iiiiiiii
```

"M" for most significant bit, "L" for least significant bit, "i" for ignored (shifted right), "r" for returned.

As to how that is done, look at your C reference on bitshift and bitwise operators. As to what it means semantically, that should be clear from your accompanying course material explaining what those bits  -- labeled `A1` -- signify.

Comment: *(aka "the part with the mask")* 

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that as written, this `get_bits` function doesn't support getting all 32 bits from a `uint32_t`.  In fact, since it uses `1<<` instead of `1U<<`, it also has signed-integer overflow when getting 31 bits on a system where `int` is `int32_t`.  And it assumes that `int` is at least 32 bits, but that's not guaranteed.  A more robust implementation would use `(1UL << count) - 1`.  Or two shifts, one left one right, to knock bits off, supporting any non-zero-size bitfield up to full width for uint32_t.

Comment: @PeterCordes The function is also just used with one set of parameters, and the whole code is riddled with magic numbers. I get the impression this is pretty much one-shot, so I didn't go into improving the code.

Comment: Fair enough, but the only magic numbers I see are `4` (word size) and the sizes of the register file and code + data arrays.  The numbers used for initializers aren't "magic", they just random example addresses and data. The bit-range used for the call to `get_bits` might also be hard-coded magic constants if that's a field in the normal instruction encoding for this machine.

Comment: But yeah, the use-case for `get_bits` will always be for bitfields less than 32, since no instruction has all 32 bits used for one big field in any ISA except maybe a one-instruction computer where every instruction is DJNZ so the encoding is just the branch-displacement.  And then you wouldn't call a `get_bits` function.